# How to guard against function arguments being passed in the wrong order?

Tags: c++, types, arguments, named-parameters

Say I have a C++ function that looks like this:

```
double myfunction(double a, double b) {
    // do something
}
```

Which I then call like this:

```
double a = 1.0;
double b = 2.0;
double good_r = myfunction(a, b);
double bad_r = myfunction(b, a); // compiles fine
```

I would like to make sure that `a` and `b` are never provided in the wrong order.
What is the best way to ensure this in C++?

Other languages allow named parameters, like this:

```
double good_r = myfunction(a=a, b=b);
double bad_r = myfunction(a=b, b=a); // mistake immediately obvious
double bad_r = myfunction(b=b, a=a); // compiles fine
```

Or perhaps the problem can be partly solved using types, i.e.

```
double my_type_safe_function(a_type a, b_type b) {
    // do something
}
a_type a = 1.0;
b_type b = 2.0;
double good_r = myfunction(a, b);
double bad_r = myfunction(b, a); // compilation error
```

EDIT: A couple of people have asked what I mean by the "wrong order." What I mean is that, in real code `a` and `b` have some significance. For example, the arguments might instead be `height` and `width`. The difference between them is very important for the function to return the correct result. However, they are both floats and they both have the same dimensions (i.e. a length). Also, there is no "obvious" order for them. The person writing the function declaration may assume `(width, height)` and the person using the function may assume `(height, width)`. I would like a way to ensure this doesn't happen by mistake. With two parameters it is easy to be careful with the order, but in a large project and with up to 6 arguments mistakes creep in.

Ideally I would like the checks to be done at compile time, and for there to be no performance hit (i.e. at the end of the day they are treated as plain old floats or whatever).

Comment: What is the difference between `a` and `b` that makes them being in the wrong order incorrect? Is it possible you can verify their actual values, and throw an exception / exit early if they're invalid? If they're both the same type, there's no real foolproof way to stop this at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
struct typeAB {float a; float b; };

double myfunction(typeAB p) {
// do something
  return p.a - p.b;
}

int main()
{
  typeAB param;
  param.a = 1.0;
  param.b = 2.0;
  float result = myfunction(param);
  return 0;
}
```

Of course, you can still mess up when you assign your parameter(s) but that risk is hard to avoid :)

Comment: I like this solution, but imho there is a (small) performance hit from copying.

Comment: @Bgie Did you profile your code to come to that conclusion or are you just guessing what the compiler is doing?

Comment: @DDrmmr yes, I am guessing :-)

Answer (score 2):

A variant is to have one struct per "new" type, and then make them go away in optimized builds using macros.

Something along these lines (only slightly tested, so it could be way off):

```
#define SAFE 0

#if SAFE
#define NEWTYPE(name, type) \
    struct name { \
       type x; \
       explicit name(type x_) : x(x_) {}\
       operator type() const { return x; }\
    }
#else
#define NEWTYPE(name, type) typedef type name
#endif

NEWTYPE(Width, double);
NEWTYPE(Height, double);

double area(Width w, Height h)
{
    return w * h;
}

int main()
{
    cout << area(Width(10), Height(20)) << endl;

    // This line says 'Could not convert from Height to Width' in g++ if SAFE is on.
    cout << area(Height(10), Width(20)) << endl; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you already provided the easiest solution, using types.

One alternative could be using a builder class and method chaining.
Like:

```
class MyfunctionBuilder {
  MyFunctionBuilder & paramA(double value);
  MyFunctionBuilder & paramB(double value);
  double execute();
  (...)
}
```

Which you would use like this:

```
double good_r = MyFunctionBuilder().paramA(a).paramB(b).execute();
```

But this is a lot of extra code to write!

Comment: I am with Bgie here -- use types!

Comment: Is it possible to do this using simple `typedef`s?

Comment: Don't think so, I think you need small classes/structs for this, and watch out for implicit construction (Make the constructor from double explicit)

Answer (score 0):

What is the "wrong order" actually? In this example of yours

```
double myfunction(double a, double b) {
    // do something
}

double a = 1.0;
double b = 2.0;
double good_r = myfunction(a, b);
double bad_r = myfunction(b, a);
```

how do you actually want to know if this *is* the right order? What if the variables would be named "quapr" and "moo" instead of "a" and "b"? Then it would be impossible to guess whether the order is right or wrong just by looking at them.

With this in mind, you can do at least two things. First, is to give meaningfull names to the arguments, e.g.

```
float getTax( float price, float taxPercentage )
```

instead of

```
float getTax( float a, float b )
```

Second, do the necessary checks inside:

```
float divide( float dividend, float divisor )
{
    if( divisor == 0 )
    {
         throw "omg!";
    }
}
```

It is possible to do more complex checks, such as making a functor, and setting it's parameters explicitly, but in most of the cases that just complicates things without much benefit.

Comment: There are lots of cases where two (or more) same-typed values have to be passed in the correct order: e.g. creating a Rectangle (top, left, width, height... or top, left, bottom, right for that matter!). You can't reliably detect a mistake there by assert-style checks.

Comment: @AAT, 'There are lots of cases where two (or more) same-typed values have to be passed in the correct order'. How about this: _every_ function wants to take the arguments in _exactly one_ correct order. Yet I still have to see a functor (like in Bgie's answer) for creating a rectangle. Meaningful argument names and a programmer who pays minimum attention is enough in 99.9% of the time, IMO. Really, would anyone ever call a function without caring about arguments order?

Comment: oh, I agree, the right answer in C/C++ has to be well-named parameters (and variables). Things like functors and other artificial constructs are way too much trouble as a rule. I just wanted to emphasize that there are many cases where this is a _potential_ problem and assert-style checks won't help.

Comment: Ada (which I learned many years ago but have never used in anger) has a solution to this problem, which is "cheap" custom types and very strong type-checking. You can create your "own" integer or double: so for example you could have a "Top", which is just an integer but only values declared as "Top" can be passed in, and can't be mixed up with a "Bottom". You can approximate that in C/C++ by boxing values into structs, I guess.